# Is TypeScript linter being overly cautious?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous

I'm getting a warning from my linter about something in this function:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const uploadFiles = async (fileList: FileList) => {
    const uploadSessionId = getUUID();
    let mediaSetId: string | null = null;
    await getMediaSetId().then(response => {mediaSetId = response});

    for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
      const file: File = fileList[i];
      const originalFilename = file.name;
      const fileExtension = originalFilename.split('.').pop() ?? 'unknown';
      await getBase64(file).then(result => uploadFile(result, originalFilename, fileExtension, file.lastModified, mediaSetId, uploadSessionId));
      }
    };

    if (isUploading && fileList) {
      // Start the upload process
      uploadFiles(fileList);
    }
}, [isUploading, fileList]);
```

The exact error message is: `Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'mediaSetId'`

When building it, I first thought about putting the `for` loop within the `.then` clause but chose to do it as above, whereby I instantiate `mediaSetId = null` and then the `async` function call populates it accordingly.

Is this approach I've used "wrong"?  It all seems to be working as expected by the way.

Comment: Wait, if you have `async` already, why not just use `const mediaSetId: string = await getMediaSetId();`?

Comment: Thanks you for that, @VLAZ!!!

I must confess that I've gotten so confused over how to retrieve data from async functions.  I thought I HAD TO use the `.then` approach.  But your approach works great and removes the aforementioned linting error!

The exact code I'm using now is: `const mediaSetId: string|null = await getMediaSetId();`

Comment: You don't need `string|null` if `getMediaSetId()` only returns strings. If it's guaranteed to do that, you can drop the `null` from the type.

Comment: Understood but `null` is very much a possibility in this case.  FYI a `null` value for `mediaSetId` means that the file will reside at the root and not in a media set (aka album).  Kind of the way Instagram works, with everything at the root level.